# In Shiny, await for the user to stop filling a table with rhandsontable

Tags: r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

Considering a user filling in by hand a `rhandsontable`, I would like to implement a time related condition to proceed with table analysis and plot. *E.g.* if nothing has been added to table during the last 2 seconds, proceed, otherwise await till the 2 seconds are past.

I tried with `validate()` or simple condition (like below). It does not work because `observe()` is accessed immediately after table is modified, at that time the time related condition is `false`. When the condition should be `true`, the `observe()` function is not accessed anymore so condition is not tested...

I tried to provide a MRE but I have trouble defending the need for such feature in a simple example. The need is related to computation time of analysis and plot.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(ggplot2)


DF <- data.frame(x=integer(0), y=integer(0))

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel( 
    rHandsontableOutput("hot"),
    plotOutput("plot1")
  )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$table <- DF
  values$accessDF <- 0

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
      DF <- hot_to_r(input$hot)
      values$accessDF <- Sys.time() # reset awaiting time when table is incremented
    } else {
      if (is.null(values[["DF"]]))
        DF <- DF
      else
        DF <- values[["DF"]]
    }
    values[["DF"]] <- DF
  })

  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(values[["DF"]], stretchH = "all", minRows=5)
  })

  observe({

    if (Sys.time() - values$accessDF > 2){ # unfornate try...
      # some modification of the table occuring here
      values$table <- values$DF
    }

  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(data=values$table) + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y))

  })

})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to let your plot depend on a debounced reactive expression that contains the reactive value:

```r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput("hot"),
    plotOutput("plot1")
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv = reactiveVal(data.frame(x = integer(0), y = integer(0)))

  r2 = reactive(rv()) |>
    debounce(2000)

  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(rv(), stretchH = "all", minRows = 5)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(r2(), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
      geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) +
      geom_line(na.rm = TRUE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$hot$changes, {
    rv(hot_to_r(input$hot))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution. Use `reactiveTimer()` to force the `observe()` to activate even though no variable it observes has been updated.

in `server:`

`autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(200) # to activate observer every 200 ms`

and then in `observe()`

`autoInvalidate()`

followed by the condition

```
if (Sys.time() - values$accessDF > 2){ # unfornate try...
  # some modification of the table occuring here
  values$table <- values$DF
}
```

see https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.0/reactiveTimer.html